# data.table How to copy a column programmatically?

Tags: r, data.table

```r
library(data.table)
irisDT = as.data.table(iris)
```

I am looking for this:

```r
irisDT[, NewCol:= Sepal.Length]
```

but then programmatically, so with `var = "Sepal.Length"`.

I would expect something like this:

```r
var = "Sepal.Length"
irisDT[, NewCol := eval(var)]
```

This

```r
var = "Sepal.Length"
irisDT$NewCol = irisDT[[var]]
```

works, but `irisDT` is copied internally, which is undesirable.

Any help is welcome:-)

Comment: Use get instead of eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be an option for you?

```
irisDT[, NewCol := get(..var)]
```

You can use `get(var)` as long there is no variable in your `data.table` that is called `var` so programmatically using `..var` is safer (see also [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#datatable-v1102--31-jan-2017)).

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for.